# Explicit Sharing with watch action is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, action, facebook-opengraph, watch

I am trying to use Explicit Sharing with built in watch action. Here is my code

> $post_action = $facebook->api(
>
> > ```
> > 'me/video.watches',
> > 'POST',
> > array(
> >   'video' => "$post-link",
> >   'fb:explicitly_shared'=>true
> > )
> > ```
> >
> > );

When I set fb:explicitly_shared to false the activity is shown on both recent activity and activity log. But when i set it to true the activity is only shown on activity log, not to the recent activity, not to the users timeline.

I have read all the documentation on Facebook about Explicit Sharing but i cant find out why is this happening.

All the results I mentioned are made with Test Users of this app.
Maybe I have first to submit it on Facebook for approval before I will be able to test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some days of work i found out that Application testers have a bug with explicit share. I tried to post with my developers account and works good!

Comment: facebook api is full of bug